# Pentaho storage folder variable

Tags: variables, pentaho

Pentaho stores files created by job or transformation under /data-integration folder. Do you know the variable which I can overwrite and save my files under other directory?

Comment: what step you used to generate the said files?

Comment: Text file output, Microsoft Excel Writer - I don't want to add variable to each of those steps in order to store files in a specific folder. I thought there is a global variable which you can overwrite.

Comment: Have you created a repository?

Comment: yes, I have repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDI solution for this is to define the filename as `${my_dir}/my_file`,
where `my_dir` is a variable to be replaced at runtime by its value.

To define a variable, right-click anywhere in spoon main screen to bring the dropmenu, select `Properties` then `Parameters`, and add `my-dir` in the table, optionally with a default value.

When you run the job/transformation, you are presented a table of parameters, among which `my_dir`, to you have the opportunity to change the default.

There are many others ways to define a variable. For example, the `Set variable` / `Get Variable` let you change the variable from transformation to transformations in a job.

An other (very) usefull way is to define the variable in the `kettle.properties` that you can access from the `main menu/edit/` and is staranard file in the `.kettle` directory in `c:\User\yourname\` (Windows) directory or you installation directory (linux). The properties will overwrite the default values at runtime. The magic of this approach is that you can have a `kettle.properties` on your dev-machine, different from the one on the prod-server or the ones of your co-workers. A pretty handy solution especially for databases and url connections and passwords.

There is much more to say, because the PDI machinery goes ways further than rewriting an environment variable (which I guess is `${user.dir}`).

And one more thing: you can popup a selectable list of variables almost anywhere it makes sense by pressing <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.